# Download files in windows phone Silverlight 8.1 apps

Tags: c#

I have code to download videos from the internet. My code can run in a runtime app but it can't run in a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app.

```
private async void dinhmenh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile destinationFile;
    try
    {         
        destinationFile = await  KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Baihay" + ".mp4",
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        MessageBox.Show("1");
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("2"+ destinationFile.ToString());
    // MessageBox
    try
    { 
        downloadLink = new Uri("url", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        _download = downloader.CreateDownload(downloadLink, destinationFile);
        await _download.StartAsync(); ;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    await HandleDownloadAsync();
    MessageBox.Show("Finish!");
}
```

Comment: is an exception thrown? is there an error?

Comment: Thank for reading :) this is error
"System.Exception: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(Uri uri, IStorageFile resultFile)
   at PageDl.MainPage.<dinhmenh_Click>d__7.MoveNext()"

Comment: plz, Who can help me?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?